# Prove that $n$ doesn't divide $3^n+1$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that any odd integer $n>1$ Doesn't divide

$3^n+1$

I know that Fermat's little theorem will be useful in this problem but have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: @Galc127 30 is even, but is divisible by 3 and 5.

Comment: @NicNic8, you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $n$ is such a number. Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $n$, and $\alpha=\text{ord}_p(3)$. On the one hand, $\alpha\mid p-1$ and on the other hand $\alpha\mid2n$ since $3^{2n}\equiv1\pmod n$. From the choice of $p$ as the smallest prime divisor it follows from $\alpha\mid2n$ that $\alpha\mid2$, hence $p\mid3^2-1=8$. But $p$ is odd, contradiction. $\square$

Comment: Remember: if you get struck, take at look at the smallest/largest prime divisor. It is a typical trick.

Comment: what does $ord_p(3)$ mean?

Comment: The multiplicative order of $3$ modulo $p$. If this is the first time you hear about order, I suggest you to study some of its properties because otherwise the entire solution will be a mystery to you.

Comment: @Bart Michels can you please tell how does $\alpha$ divides 2n implies $\alpha$ | 2 ?

Comment: Take any prime number $q \mid n$. Because $p$ is minimal, $p \leq q$. Because $\alpha < p$, we have $\alpha < q$, so that $q \nmid \alpha $. Hence $\gcd(n, \alpha) = 1$.